# using jest, how to console log the value of text input?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Using jest and react testing library, how can I log the value of a text input?
So if you have

```
<Input data-testid="myid" />
```

I want something like

```
const myelement = screen.getByTestId('myid');

console.log("value=" +myelement.value  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you did it correctly

If you don't see the value, the input field possibly does not have any value

```
import { fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'

//your unit test logic
const myelement = screen.getByTestId('myid')
fireEvent.change(myelement, { target: { value: 'your value' } }) //to add a value to the input field
console.log('value=' + myelement.value) // it will log `your value`
```

Another way you can try is setting up your default value on the input field

```
<Input data-testid="myid" value="your value"/>
```

If it does not work, please share your `Input` component with me, I may find another way to help.

Comment: What fixed it was per your suggestion I did "fireEvent.change" instead of "fireEvent.type". thanks!